# How to understand the infinite dimensional space?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am trying to understand the infinite dimensional space such as $L^2$ space
\begin{align}
\langle f,g\rangle = \int f(x) \bar{g}(x)dx.
\end{align}
where $\bar{g}$ denote the conjugate of $g$.
I have this question when I am trying to understand the Fourier transform in **a more general framework**. We know the  Fourier transform is given by
\begin{align}
F(w)=\langle f(x),g_w(x)\rangle = \int f(x)\bar{g}_w(x)dx,
\end{align}
where $g_w(x) = e^{j2\pi wx}$.

I want to **generalize the Fourier transform** to the case with arbitrary $g_w(x)$.
From my understanding, $F(w)$ can be treated as the probjection on the function $g_w(x)$.

Similary as the Fourier function, the only condition I impose on the $g_w(x)$ is the orthogonality. Specifically, we assume that $\langle g_{w_1}(x),g_{w_2}(x) \rangle = 0, \forall w_1 \neq w_2$. Thus, $\{g_{w}(x): w \in \mathbb{R}\}$ forms the **orthogonal basis of the function, not necessarily the Fourier function**.

Considering the intuition of projection and basis, then we can have something like that
\begin{align}
f(x) = \sum_w F(w)g_w(x)
\end{align}
The diffenrence is that the number of basis function $\{g_{w}(x): w \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is infinite. We should have integration instead of summation,
\begin{align} 
f(x) = C\int \langle f,g_{w} \rangle g_w(x) dw      ~~~~~~~~~~(1)           
\end{align}
where $C$ is some constant. This equation (1) is just my intuition not a strict proof.

---

**My question** is that do we have some theorem or lemma which support the equation (1) when the orthogonality holds for $g_w(x)?$ By the way, I know (1) holds for Fourier function, and here I am focusing on arbitrary basis function $g_w(x)$.

Comment: Yes, it is called Parselval identity (theorem). Also, technically speaking one still has to prove that $g_w$  form a basis in $L^2$.

Comment: Orthogonality of the collection of vectors does not imply it’s completeness as @Salcio mentioned. But otherwise yes, what you need there is just any orthonormal  basis

Comment: @Ilya, do you mean that we require that $g_w$ should be orthonormal basis?

Comment: It's more complicated than that for the Fourier transform, since $g_w$ is not in $L^2$. Either you start with Fourier series, which are conceptually simpler (recommended), or you need to study the concept of "rigged Hilbert space" to do what you are planning with the Fourier transform. I don't recommend the latter, as you do not really need this concept to understand the Fourier transform.